# Minimum of $|\det(X+iC)|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, determinant

Let $C$ be a fixed real $n\times n$ matrix, $X$ be an arbitrary real $n\times n$ matrix. Find the minimum value of:

$$|\det(X+iC)|=\sqrt{\det(X+iC)\det(X-iC)}$$

When $n=1$ it's clear that the minimum value equal $|C|$, however it seems like with $n\ge2$ the minimum value is exactly zero, but I don't know how to prove it.

I have found out that this is relating to the minimum of $\det(I+Q^2)$ with $I$ is identity and $Q$ is arbitrary real matrix. If you can evaluate either:

- $|\det(X+iC)|$
- $\det(I+Q^2)$

it would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that $\det(X+iC)\det(X-iC) = \det((X+iC)(X-iC)) = \det(X^2-C^2 + i[C,X])$, with $[C,X] = CX - XC \ne 0$ in general. So that second form is not equal to the original one.

Comment: It's just related, thks for pointing out anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any $C$, one can always find an $X$ such that $\det(X+iC)=0$ : if $C$ is not invertible, simply take $X=0$. If $C$ is invertible, take
$X=CA$ where $A$ is any real matrix having a two-dimensional invariant
subspace ${\sf span}(v_1,v_2)$ with $Av_1=v_2$, $Av_2=-v_1$ (so that
$\pm i$ are eigenvalues of $A$). Then

$$
\det(X+iC)=\det(C(A+iI_n))=\det(C)\times 0=0.
$$

**Update** I’ve just realized that my second case construction works in all cases, there’s no need to assume that $C$ is invertible.

Comment: @achillehui A few hours ago I proposed another, now deleted, simple and elegant (but completely wrong) answer :-)

Comment: @mvw corrected, thanks.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy The hardest bit for me to understand your argument is that it is always possible to provide a real matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\pm i$. Your construction gives an $A$ with $A^2 v_1 = - v_1$ and $A^2 v_2 = - v_2$. So $A^2$ has the eigenvalue $-1$. I lack the argument how that implies $A$ has eigenvalue $i$.

Comment: @mvw Consider $Av$ where $v=v_1-iv_2$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume true that the minimum is zero it means that we can minimize separately the real part and the imaginary part.
Let n=2, knowing that $\det(X+iC)=\det(X)+i(\det(x_1,c_2)+\det(c_1,x_2))-\det(C)$ then it means that $\det(X)=\det(C)$ and $\det(x_1,c_2)=\det(x_2,c_1)$ where $x_i$ and $c_i$ represents the i-st columns of the matrices $X$ and $C$ respectively. If $\det(C)=0$ we would have that $X=C$ would be a minimizer with value $0$, so we can assume that $\det(C)\neq0$.
We end the argument taking $X=(c_2,-c_1)$.

If $n>2$ we can note that taking $X=(c_2,-c_1,c_3,\dots,c_n)$ will give us: $$X+iC=(c_2+ic_1,-c_1+ic_2,\dots)=(c_2+ic_1,i(c_2+ic_1),\dots)$$
Which is clearly singular.

On a same note $\det(I+Q^2)=0$ if on some two dimensional space $Q$ is a rotation of a $\frac{\pi}{2}$ angle. Again if $n=2$ 
$$Q=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
then $Q^2=-I$. If $n>2$ then as written above it is needed that $\exists v_1, v_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $\|v_1\|=\|v_2\|$ and $Qv_1=v_2$ and $Qv_2=-v_1$.

Comment: $\det(X+iC)=\det(X)+i(\det(x_1,c_2)+\det(c_1,x_2))-\det(C)$ for $n=2$

Comment: I don't really understand your argument..

Comment: I think Ewan just explained it. Or are you talking about my comment about the determinant?

Comment: Is it a problem of notation? $c_1$ is the first column of the $C$ matrix, the same goes for $x_1$. From the definition of the determinant follows the property that I wrote 2 hours ago.

Comment: @Lolman I agree with your argument for $n=2$. But for $n > 2$ you would need to provide another expansion for $\det(X+iC)$.

Comment: It is a solution to the equation $\det(X+iC)=0$ what else is needed? it is just a check. The idea is given from the $n=2$ case but it works in all cases. The question asked for a solution, once you find one that works for all $n\geq1$ we are done. The formula for the determinant can be generalized but it is not needed to see that my solution works.